# Problems with Hibernate + JPA on Jetty

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, jetty

I created a web application with vaadin framework which uses hibernate and persistence.xml to access my postgresql database. The application runs fine on my wildfly. When wildfly deploys the war, it creates the database schema.

Now i have tried to use the app with jetty, but hibernate does not trigger the schema creation. I am realy new to jetty and i cant figure out the problem.

The POM of my WAR uses folowing dependencies for Hibernate:

```
    <!--DB Driver-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1206-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Hibernate-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.Final</version>
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>

<resource-ref>
    <description>SeApp Postgres Datasource</description>
    <res-ref-name>java:/jdbc/SeAppDS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

My jetty-env.xml in WEB_INF:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
<New id="DSTest" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>java:/jdbc/SeAppDS</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource">
            <Set name="User">user</Set>
            <Set name="Password">password</Set>
            <Set name="DatabaseName">seapp</Set>
            <Set name="ServerName">localhost</Set>
            <Set name="PortNumber">5432</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

and my persitence.xml in META-INF:

```
<persistence-unit name="SeAppPU" transaction-type="JTA">
<jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/SeAppDS</jta-data-source>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
</properties>
```

Comment: you mean, when you create the EntityManagerFactory?

Comment: With wildfly i dont have to create an EntityManagerFactory. On deploy hibernate automatically create the schema. Do i need this with jetty?

Comment: Wildfly is a JavaEE implementation. Jetty is not. You did read the Jetty docs didn't you?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Found it in the [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-javaee.html)